# Storyboard & 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, runtime-error

NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'DetayViewController''

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    DetayViewController *liste = [[DetayViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetayViewController" bundle:nil];

    if ([[akdeniz objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Antalya"]) {
        liste.ptrs =0;
        [liste setTitle:[akdeniz objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    }

    if ([[ege objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"Aydın"]) {
        liste.ptrs =1;
        [liste setTitle:[ege objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:liste animated:YES];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = someViewController.storyboard;
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetayViewController"];
```

or if it's your first view controller

```
storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" /*whatever*/ bundle:nil];
```

Comment: You might need to set the identifier (I usually use the same as class).

Comment: hmm What else can I do